# Cascading List Views with knockout

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui

I have an viewmodel with an observable array of objects, and a computed selectedObject.  I'm attempting to bind a KendoListView to an observable array in selectedObject, but the ListView doesn't get updated.

There's a fiddle demonstrating the issue here:

http://jsfiddle.net/JrJ2q/3/

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="kendoListView: {  data: fruits, template: template, selectable:'single', change: function(e){ selectedId(this.select().index())} }" ></div>
<hr/>
<div data-bind="kendoListView: {data: selectedChoice.seeds, template: template2 }"></div>
<hr/>
Selected Id: <strong data-bind="text: selectedId"> </strong>
<hr/>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(selectedChoice, null, 2)"></pre>
```

javascript:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
template = '<div>#=name#</div>';
template2 = '<div>Anything</div>';
fruits = ko.observableArray([
    { id: "0", name: "apple", seeds: [
     {number: "1"},{number:"2"},{number:"3"}]
    },
    { id: "1", name: "orange", seeds: [
     {number: "11"},{number:"12"},{number:"13"}]
    },
    { id: "2", name: "banana", seeds: [
     {number: "21"},{number:"22"},{number:"23"}]
    }
]);

selectedId = ko.observable();
selectedChoice = ko.computed(function() {
    var id = selectedId();
    if (id) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(fruits(), function(fruit) {
           return fruit.id === id; 
        });
    }

}, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

I'd appreciate any support the community can provide!

Thanks

Comment: you know there is extra **}** in your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from having an extra `}` in your code, you had a problem with the binding of "seeds":

1. You have to bind on `selectedChoice().seeds`, not `selectedChoice.seeds` because `selectedChoice` is a function, and as such...
2. You have to to check when binding on `selectedChoice().seeds` that `selectedChoice` is not `null`, otherwise the binding will fail and your app crashes, and nothing works anymore.

To solve the second problem, you can either apply the following binding:

```
<div data-bind="data: selectedChoice() ? selectedChoice().seeds: []">/div>
```

... or create a "selectedSeeds" computed function that will do the same thing, but it adds readability to your code.

Also, to set the "id" of the selected item you have to write this:

```
selectedId(evt.sender.dataSource.view()[evt.sender.select().index()].id)
```

Where `evt` is the change event.

Here's the working result, on a [forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rs9c7/).

Comment: Thanks Jalayn, I had taken out the null check and selection of the id property and used the index to simplify the example, but should have updated my model to reflect that (changed id -> index).  Of course I should have realized that being an observable it'd be a function... Thanks again!